# Pass Public Key, Private Key and CA In stream_get_contents() Call for Multipart/Related

Tags: php, ssl

I am attempting to connect to a 3rd party API, and they require me to pass 3 certificate files they have given me: public cert, private cert, and CA cert. It works fine in cURL with the following settings:

```
if (empty($this->order['connector'])) {
    curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, API_PRIVATE_CERT);
    curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, API_CA_CERT);
    curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, API_PUBLIC_CERT);
}
```

Each value passed is a path to a physical file on the server. This works fine.

With one request, however, I have to pass a header 'Content-Type: Multipart/Related; boundary="---BOUNDARY123456"' with a MIME message that contains an XML file and a Base64 encoded PDF. This fails with a 500 error on their end. And in researching this, I have seen cURL cannot properly handle Content-Type: Multipart/Related posts.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25998544/3434084

So I have tried to send it using stream_get_contents(), but I get no response back. So I am thinking my cert data is wrong. How can I pass the same values I use in cURL via stream_get_contents()?

Here's the code:

```
$payload = '----=FB498299F0F50D2A190B3C
Content-Type: application/x-ofx

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?OFX OFXHEADER="200" VERSION="201" SECURITY="NONE" OLDFILEUID="NONE" NEWFILEUID="NONE"?>
<OFX>
        <SIGNONMSGSRQV1>
                <SONRQ>
                        <LANGUAGE>ENG</LANGUAGE>
                        <APPID>TWEEN</APPID>
                </SONRQ>
        </SIGNONMSGSRQV1>
        ...
</OFX>

----=FB498299F0F50D2A190B3C
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Location: full1_1559588546.pdf

JVBERi0xLjQKJcOkw7zDtsOfCjIgMCBvYmoKPDwvTGVuZ3RoIDM...PRgo=
----=FB498299F0F50D2A190B3C' . "\r\n\r\n";

$params = [
    'http' => [
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => 'Content-Type: Multipart/Related; boundary="----=FB498299F0F50D2A190B3C"',
        'content' => $payload
    ],
    'ssl'  => [
        'verify_peer' => true,
        'local_pk'    => API_PRIVATE_CERT,
        'cafile'      => API_CA_CERT,
        'local_cert'  => API_PUBLIC_CERT
    ]
];

$_stream = stream_context_create($params);
$response = @file_get_contents('https://blah/api/, FILE_TEXT, $_stream);
```

TIA!

Comment: you suppress errors in your example which sort of prevents trouble-shooting I guess. To further trouble-shoot you can try hooking stream notifications (events) and maybe setting timeouts to low values can help w/ trouble-shooting as well. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/stream.errors.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-notification-callback.php - Last but not least, this Q&A material looks also interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40999726/367456

Comment: Found another multipart/related w/ curl in PHP related Q&A, even with an accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9252130/367456 /e: it specifically points out: "Note, the last boundary has an additional `--` at the end." also the lines in your payload are not \r\n terminated, I don't know for the mime-type specifically, but the details should be here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2387 (perhaps)

Comment: @hakre Thanks for the link! I thought I had seen every page and tried every sample here in regards to multipart/related. Will take a look.

Comment: It's always like that, information overflow. From what I've seen so far, it's not that curl does not per-se can't do that, it's just that you need to encode the payload your own as curl can't encode multipart/related, however sending it (and with your SSL options) does work as you told. So I'd say this should not be a show stopper in using curl (however the other question about what goes wrong with the HTTP/SSL stream is interesting as well). But as you already have curl working with the certs, I would just focus on the payload encoding as multipart/related.

Comment: @hakre The original code I had used all of the same cURL code, but I hand built the payload so it matched what the end-use API needed. But they report 500 errors w/ very little info to glean. Just frustrating. :(

Comment: Yes I can understand. I guess you don't have the sever logs so that you could learn more about the 500 reason and yeah, that moves things more far away which is a burden on trouble shooting. I also left some hints on how to better inspect for streams, I have a pretty high rated answer for debugging curl in PHP which might be of use if you currently opt to curl: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14436877/367456 - with further links which for curl is normally the first thing I do when I want to learn more where things go south.

Comment: Adding your PHP version to the question might make sense, too. E.g. default values for the stream context option, esp. w/ ssl/tls has undergone changes  over time (normally the more recent the more strict the verification is).

Comment: @hakre It's running now on PHP 5.6, but next year will need to run on 7.x. I am also trying https://github.com/robtimus/php-multipart to see if it does it, as well.

Comment: Now that's great to read. If you put your learnings as an answer below it's kept for a longer time and for others this might be of use, too. Th emultipart lib looks nice on first sight, thanks for the link.

Comment: This ended up being a non-issue. There were initial issues with my cURL code that caused me not to send the headers properly. Once I fixed that, it made the above code no longer needed, as my regular cURL code worked, as expected. Thanks to @hakre for the great responses and advice.

Comment: Oh, it would be nice if you could add that as an answer and maybe give a bit more of a technical hint where you got stuck so that if future users find it can not only learn that it's possible but also how to trouble-shoot. You can also mark that kind of answer then as the solution which will make this totally clear (and it's not so much of a need to go through all the comments),. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$params = [
    "ssl"=>[
        "verify_peer"=> true,
        "verify_peer_name"=> true,
        "cafile" => "pem.pem",
    ],
];

$response = file_get_contents($URL, 0, stream_context_create($params)
```

Comment: Thanks for the post, but I also need to pass the public and private key. What keys under SSL would those values go to>

Comment: @JoelF.: From what I've seen yesterday, what you do already looks pretty good to me. I checked that at least from docs. I don't have a setup at hand which is similar to test that configuration fully. I'm pretty sure, in the end this is possible w/ streams (and I also think with curl). This is "just" (tm) finding where the configuraiton is broken. Actually, let's face it: if there is a 500, that means the transport layer made it, right? This is more that the encoding of the payload is wrong and the other server borks (or the HTTP version etc. pp.).

Comment: @hakre Thanks for all of the help. I agree that the payload does send, but they're not going to fix it on their side, so I am stuck determining why.

Answer (score -1):

It turns out my issues was with the original cURL code I had used that was failing. Here's the updated code I needed to use in this case to send multipart/related content via cURL, using the 3rd party's SSL certificate data provided to me to authenticate access.

```
$headers = [
    'Content-Type: Multipart/Related; boundary="--' . $this->api_boundary . '";type=text/xml'
];

$_curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_URL, $this->api_url);
curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, FALSE);
curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->api_xml);
curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

// TLS items
curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, API_PRIVATE_CERT); // path to private cert in .pem format
curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, API_CA_CERT); // path to CA cert in .pem format
curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, API_PUBLIC_CERT); // path to public cert in .pem format

// process
$response = curl_exec($_curl);

// check for errors
if (curl_error($_curl)) {
    // capture error here
}

$status   = curl_getinfo($_curl);
curl_close($_curl);
```

Comment: @Dharman You're rihgt. I had it off on my dev machine b/c the SSL wouldn;t validate. Production does. Answer updated.

Comment: Tht values are still wrong. Just remove those lines and let the default values be.